# Set special characters in Zend Form from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-form

In Zend Form how do I set special characters in a text field?
The characters are saved in the database as & aacute; etc.
In my application.ini I have set the database connection with UTF like this:

```
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

The tables are set as utf8_general_ci.
And in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF=8" />
```

An example below:

```
$form->getElement('title')->setValue($Row['title']);
```

When I open a webpage it shows & aacute; just as in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a charset problem. ZF escapes data that is shown in form fields, but you're supplying an already escaped value into the form field so the escaping is happening twice. This means the ampersand is changed into `&amp;` which is why the escaped value is what you see.

I'd suggest storing the data unescaped if you can (so store á in the db, since you are using UTF-8 this will work just fine). Then you won't have this problem. Alternatively you can disable escaping on individual form elements.

Comment: Thanks alot I escaped it the the form itself.